# How to change nametag fully in Spigot protocol hacks 1.7/8 without any APIs

Tags: server, protocols, minecraft, bukkit

How do you change a player's nametag fully in Spigot Protocol hacks in 1.7/8 without any APIs? If somebody knows how to do this that would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: Which name tag are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the nametag above the player's head. @kmecpp

Comment: If you want to only change the color of the player's name tag (above their head) or add a prefix/suffix, I believe you can use the built in scoreboard teams. If you want to change the actual name, you'll need to use packets. Note that changing a player's name will, as far as I can tell, change their skin, and doesn't stop a custom client from still finding out who that player actually is/was.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be too hard to do that (maybe impossible) Because it is really hard to get into mojangs rules. And when i don't know a GUI where you can change the player nametag (I tried once one time, did not work)